# Xamarin Layout vs Xamarin Forms ContentPage XAML

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

SO I'm new in mobile dev and in xamarin.

So I try to understand - If I need some view(pages) with different content and logic - how is right way to do it?

1) Create a **ContentPage** **Xaml**

2) Or create a **layout** and **class** where I just write logic and write

**`SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LAYOUTNAME);`**

I'm web developer (**ASP**) so if you can draw a parallel with web - its be nice.

Like:

How I see - second way (**class** + **layout**) - its like

**Controller** in **asp** and page with clean **html**

first way (**ContentPage** **XAML**) - its most similar for **WebForms** or for **WPF** (and really i hate it)

But I want to know what is right way and best practice?

**Thank you**

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/

Comment: AXML Layouts apply to Android only.  XAML is the markup used by Xamarin Forms, which applies to iOS and Android.  You can also write XF UI in code without XAML.  There is no "right way" - what you choose depends on your requirements and your preferences as a developer.

Comment: Oh ok - so if I any way will write separate iOS and Andoird app like 2 separate solutions - so I can use layouts for android app. Thank you - i will choose this way))

Comment: Android axml files are very very similar to forms xaml files, just a lot more confusing if you've used previously xaml.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Xamarin.Forms Xaml is converted to native UI when you compile and the app packages are created. In Xamarin.Forms you should use Android Layouts and iOS Story Boards only if you need something very specific for the platform you target.

If you prefer use Android Layouts and iOS StoryBoards it will be better use a native Project template (Non Xamarin.Forms project) and you can create the UI in the specific platfom projects and only share the business logic.

Xamarin.Forms is a UI framework and it helps to share UI logic using xaml.

[image: Xamarin approaches]